# Seaborn's No numeric types to aggregate error

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have a pandas data frame in this form:

```
    Country     Year        Value
0   Thailand    1989       48587.03
1   Thailand    1990       55903.07
2   Vietnam     1989      100290.04
3   Vietnam     1990      118873.59
4   India       1989      147383.02
5   India       1990      178230.05
```

The dtype of the values in `Value` is float.

I am using seaborn to float this:

```
sns.lineplot(x='Year', y='Value', hue='Country', data=topfiveot)
```

And got an error:

```
DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
```

What possibly has caused the issue?

Answer (score 7):

I think this error has more to do with pandas.groupby() than with seaborn itself. Checking to make sure that all of my numeric columns were floats worked for me. In your case

`df.Year = df.Year.astype(float)`
and
`df.Values = df.Values.astype(float)`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and it turned out the one of the columns that I was plotting was of type `object` although it had all "numeric values". Type casting it to `float` worked for me

Answer (score -1):

I suppose you want to show a plot like

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({"Country" : ["Thailand"]*2 + ["Vietnam"]*2 + ["India"]*2,
                   "Year" : np.tile([1989,1990], 3),
                   "Value" : [8,3,10,4,3,0]})

ax = df.pivot("Year", "Country", "Value").plot()
ax.ticklabel_format(axis='x', useOffset=False)
plt.show()
```

[image]

The exact same plot can be achieved with seaborn via

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({"Country" : ["Thailand"]*2 + ["Vietnam"]*2 + ["India"]*2,
                   "Year" : np.tile([1989,1990], 3),
                   "Value" : [8,3,10,4,3,0]})

ax = sns.lineplot(x='Year', y='Value', hue='Country', data=df)
ax.ticklabel_format(axis='x', useOffset=False)
plt.show()
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're proposing the problem was or how your code is different from OP's. I also have the same problem and your code still gives me the same error.

Comment: @Steven The code isn't different from OPs, but the data may be. That is to show how the data needs to look like such that the code works. There is no information about data types in the question, so one cannot answer the question about the reason for the failure.